# Using fail2ban, ipset and iptables to block bad IP addresses on Google Compute Engine

Tags: iptables, google-compute-engine, fail2ban, ipset

I am running Ubuntu Linux 16.04  on a GCP Compute Engine VM instance.  This is hosting a web server for a web application.  I need feedback from the community about verification that what I have set up on Ubuntu Linux is correct and that I can verify that bad IP addresses are in fact getting blocked.

I have set up *fail2ban* and created the following jail:

```
#To stop DOS attack from remote host.    
[http-get-dos]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = http-get-dos
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log
maxretry = 1
findtime = 86400
bantime = -1
ignoreip = 111.222.333.12

# action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
banaction=iptables-ipset-proto4
```

I have *ipset* and *iptables* configured as follows:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set f2b-http-get-dos src -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -m set --match-set f2b-http-get-dos src -j DROP
```

When I query the *ipset* set name *f2b-http-get-dos*, I see numerous members listed. For example:

```
Name: f2b-http-get-dos    
Type: hash:ip    
Revision: 4    
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536    
Size in memory: 3928    
References: 3    
Number of entries: 83    
Members:    
XX.XXX.XX.XX
XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

When I query *iptables* I see (excerpted):

```
sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set f2b-http-get-dos src        
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https match-set f2b-http-get-dos src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable    
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)    
target     prot opt source               destination    
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             match-set f2b-http-get-dos src
```

How do I know and confirm that the banned IP addresses that are listed in the set named in *ipset* are being *firewalled* by *iptables*?  Does *iptables* write a log file that it maintains that tracks IP addresses it intercepted and blocked using a rule or finding the IP in an defined set name via *ipset*.

Answer (score 0):

**To check you setup** you can configure logging of iptable actions. Keep in mind, when a rule matches in iptables and the target is *DROP* or *REJECT*, that action is taken and processing stops. If you want to have a *LOG* rule, it must come before you *DROP* or *REJECT* a packet. You can try to configure a rule like this:

```
-I INPUT -m set --match-set f2b-http-get-dos src -j LOG
```

before your *DROP* rule:

```
-I INPUT -m set --match-set f2b-http-get-dos src -j DROP
```

[Here](https://www.linode.com/community/questions/11238/solved-logging-drop-records-iptables) you can find similar question.

**As an alternative solution** you can try to use [Cloud Armor WAF](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/new-waf-capabilities-in-cloud-armor) which provides built-in defenses against L3 and L4 DDoS attacks, IP-based and geo-based access control and [more](https://cloud.google.com/armor#all-features).

Answer (score 0):

You can see logs generated by [kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348439/where-can-i-find-the-iptables-log-file-and-how-can-i-change-its-location) in `/var/log/kern.log`

or you could [filter](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-check-ip-blocked-against-iptables/) them with grep:

```
# iptables -L INPUT -v -n | grep "1.2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ipset -L`  to see the list of banned IP addresses (added by fail2ban).

Example:

```
root@server:/# ipset -L
Name: f2b-sshd
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 4
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 184
References: 1
Number of entries: 2
Members:
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```